# Execute output from sp_help_revlogin in sql job

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a bugger of a time figuring this out.  I need to run `sp_help_revlogin` in a sql job (scheduled fashion).  The output of `sp_help_revlogin` would normally be copied and pasted to another query window and then executed.

I need to essentially do the same thing but in an automated sql job.  Is there a way to run `sp_help_revlogin` and execute the output in a sql job?

Step 1 - Run `sp_help_revlogin`

Step 2 - Execute the output from step 1

---

Here's what I'm doing for the complete process so far, but I get a binary error on the SID. See comments below.

CREATE TABLE #tmpLogins(
    createLoginScript NVARCHAR(4000)
)
INSERT INTO #tmpLogins
EXEC [FROMLINKEDSERVER].[master].[dbo].[sp_help_revlogin]

DECLARE @createLoginStatement nvarchar(128)
DECLARE curCreate CURSOR FOR

```
SELECT createLoginScript FROM #tmpLogins
```

OPEN curCreate
FETCH NEXT FROM curCreate INTO @createLoginStatement;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

```
EXEC sp_executesql @createLoginStatement
FETCH NEXT FROM curCreate INTO @createLoginStatement;
```

END
CLOSE curCreate;
DEALLOCATE curCreate;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpLogins') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpLogins
GO

Comment: Sorry, the formatting went to crap, just copy out to a query window and reformat.

Answer (score 1):

sp_help_revlogin is just a script that you downloaded from micrsoft so you can actually just change it.

My revision returns a table that can be parsed and in the end just do exec(@myRowVal) or google execute dynamic sql in t-sql.

Or if you feel like living dangerously ;) you can just execute it directly in the script, where I do "insert into @output"  you could just change it to "exec(@tmpstr)"

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin_With_Output @login_name sysname = NULL 

            AS
            DECLARE @name sysname
            DECLARE @type varchar (1)
            DECLARE @hasaccess int
            DECLARE @denylogin int
            DECLARE @is_disabled int
            DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
            DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
            DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
            DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
            DECLARE @tmpstr  varchar (1024)
            DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
            DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

            DECLARE @defaultdb sysname

            declare @output table
                (
                    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                    cmd varchar(max)
                )


            IF (@login_name IS NULL)
              DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR

                  SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
            sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
                  ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name <> 'sa'
            ELSE
              DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR


                  SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin FROM 
            sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l
                  ON ( l.name = p.name ) WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name = @login_name
            OPEN login_curs

            FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
            IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
            BEGIN
              PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
              insert into @output (cmd) values ( 'No login(s) found.')
              CLOSE login_curs
              DEALLOCATE login_curs
              RETURN -1
            END
            SET @tmpstr = '/* sp_help_revlogin script '
            PRINT @tmpstr
            SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'
            PRINT @tmpstr
            PRINT ''
            WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
            BEGIN
              IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
              BEGIN
                PRINT ''
                SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name
                PRINT @tmpstr
                IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
                BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group

                  SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'

                END
                ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
                    -- obtain password and sid
                        SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
                    EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
                    EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT

                    -- obtain password policy state
                    SELECT @is_policy_checked = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
                    SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name

                        SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
                    IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
                    BEGIN
                      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
                    END
                    IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
                    BEGIN
                      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
                    END
                END
                IF (@denylogin = 1)
                BEGIN -- login is denied access
                  SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
                END
                ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
                BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
                  SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
                END
                IF (@is_disabled = 1)
                BEGIN -- login is disabled
                  SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
                END
                PRINT @tmpstr
                insert into @output (cmd) values (@tmpstr)
              END

              FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin
               END
            CLOSE login_curs
            DEALLOCATE login_curs
            select * from @output
            RETURN 0
            GO
```

Comment: This is really helpful.  I am getting an error though.  Did you mess with the way the SID is created?

Supplied parameter sid should be binary(16).

Comment: It was my bad, found that my declare was too short, thus chopping off the create statement.

createLoginScript NVARCHAR(4000)